# Changing number of a web page (in the URL), change the display but not the Html source code

Tags: html, ajax, http

I am facing a behavior that I really don't understand.

If you go on the webpage: **https://www.edel-optics.fr/Lunettes-de-soleil.html#ful_iPageNumber=1** and inspect the code you will realize that it's the same html content as on **https://www.edel-optics.fr/Lunettes-de-soleil.html#ful_iPageNumber=7**

=> to test it, try to search "ERIKA - 710/T5" on both source codes and you will find it (but you should only find on the ful_iPageNumber=1).

Why is it behaving like this ?

Secondary question: how to I get the real content of **https://www.edel-optics.fr/Lunettes-de-soleil.html#ful_iPageNumber=7** ?

Thank you for your help

John

Comment: What was the first question?

Comment: Learn about Javascript.

Comment: @Musa It was implied on the problem description, but I updated for you to understand ;)

Comment: @SLaks this is your answer ? seriously ? What is the purpose of this website ? for sure not to throw useless "advices" as you do

Comment: I don't know what browser you're using but with Firefox 58 it updates the source view just fine.

Comment: @devius I am using Firefox 58.0.2, so you did not find the reference "ERIKA - 710/T5" in the **ful_iPageNumber=7** ?

Comment: @devius Are you sure about your answer ? I tried with Chrome too, same issue...

Comment: Yep, both the actual page view and the source view updated just fine with the new content when changing the id. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 although that shouldn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: Devius is probably talking about the DOM and not the source also **JavaScript**

Comment: I have updated my answer: the URL has #query=
You need to set query to match what the user has searched for

Post your script so that we can advise you where its gone wrong, ie the form, or backend

Answer (score -1):

**Problem**
You have explained that when you perform a search, you get the same results as with your pagination (page 1)

**Issue**
You are not getting the value your searching for placed into the URL
https://www.edel-optics.fr/Recherche.html?time=1519871844737#query=

the #query is = to nothing

You would be needing something like:
https://www.edel-optics.fr/Recherche.html?time=1519871844737#query=ERIKA%20-%20710/T5

Without seing your code its hard to say where the issue lays. it could well be that the search box is not inside the Form or it could be that the submit button is on another form to the search box, or maybe an issue with backend scripts not grabbing the get values as a result of case differences in the value name.
Without seing your script its hard to diagnose

Answer (score -2):

Ok I found a solution to solve this strange problem, replace the # in the URL with a ? and you will have the actual html content (corresponding to the display)...